# Symfony2 autocomplete form bundle

Tags: forms, symfony

I use this bundle: [GenemuFormBundle](https://github.com/genemu/GenemuFormBundle)
I install it due to all information on this site.

But it still dont work. 
**Here is my type form:**

> $builder
>               ->add('PermitsCompany', 'genemu_jqueryautocompleter_entity', array(
>                   'route_name' => 'ajax_company',
>                   'class' => 'MainCoreBundle:Company',
>                   'property'=>'name'
>               ))
>           ;

**Here is my routing:**

```
ajax_company:
  defaults: { _controller: MainAdminBundle:Permits:ajaxCompany}
  pattern:  /ajax_company/
  type:     annotation
```

**And here is my controller:**

```
/**
     * @Route("/ajax_company", name="ajax_company")
     */
    public function ajaxCompanyAction(Request $request)
    {


        $permits = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('MainCoreBundle:Company')->findAll();

        $json = array();
        foreach ($permits as $permit) {
            $json[] = array(
                'label' => $permit->getName(),
                'value' => $permit->getId()
            );
        }

        $response = new Response(json_encode($json));
        $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        return $response;

    }
```

I have no idea what I am doing wrong. I have no error. But autocomplete did not work.
When i go to route /ajax_company/ i can see values from data base like here:

```
[{"property":"Company 1","value":1},{"property":"Company 2","value":2},{"Company":"Company 3","value":3},{"property":"Company 4","value":4}]
```

Did I add forget something in twig? I have only form_widget

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try including `form_javascript` or `form_stylesheet`, in your twig template.

From https://github.com/genemu/GenemuFormBundle#template:

> Template
>
> You use GenemuFormBundle and you seen that it does not work! Maybe you
>   have forgotten `form_javascript` or `form_stylesheet`.
>
> The principle is to separate the javascript, stylesheet and html. This
>   allows better integration of web pages.